# Передача объекта в функцию, вызываемую после AJAX-запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли передать объект, инициализирующий AJAX-запрос, в функцию, которая выполняется после этого запроса?

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    $.get("path.php", { "query": $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        console.log($(this)); //тут хочется увидеть объект #id 
    }, 'html');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично я всегда делаю так:

```
var scope = $("#id");
scope.keyup(function() {
    $.get("path.php", { "query": $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        console.log(scope); // scope - объект #id 
    }, 'html');
})
```

Т.е. я сохраняю объект в переменную и потом использую её везде в функциях, которые обрабатывают этот самый элемент. Либо можно сделать немного по-другому:

```
$("#id").keyup(function() {
    var scope = $(this);
    $.get("path.php", { "query": scope.val() }, function(data) {
        console.log(scope); // scope - объект #id 
    }, 'html');
})
```

Comment: А что насчет конвенции, что имена переменных, содержащих `jQuery object`, должны начинаться с `$`?

Comment: @Regent как хотите) лично я называю эту переменную именно `scope` и вообще стараюсь не использовать `$`, в именах. Зачем? У меня везде jQuery, зачем мне засорять имена переменных лишним символом.

Comment: Чтобы по имени переменной была проще определить, `jQuery object` это или, например, `HTMLElement`. Не всё подряд ведь есть смысл оборачивать  с помощью _jQuery_.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего создать и вызвать анонимную функцию, передав в нее наш jQuery объект как аргумент, что сделает его видимым для всей scope функции, внутри которой уже можно с ним свободно работать.

```
;(function(element) { 
  console.log(element); // объект #id 
  element.keydown(function() {
    $.get('...', function() {
      console.log(element); // объект #id  
    });
  });
})($("#id"));
```

Преимущество этого подхода перед прочими заключается в том, что функция $ будет вызвана лишь один раз, что делает код более оптимизированным в плане производительности, да и выглядит красивей.